# Cache directory structure

Tags: caching, directory-structure

I'm in the process of implementing caching for my project. After looking at cache directory structures, I've seen many examples like:

```
cache
cache/a
cache/a/a/
cache/a/...
cache/a/z
cache/...
cache/z
...
```

You get the idea. Another example for storing files, let's say our file is named `IMG_PARTY.JPG`, a common way is to put it in a directory named:

```
files/i/m/IMG_PARTY.JPG
```

Some thoughts come to mind, but I'd like to know the real reasons for this.

- Filesystems doing linear lookups find files faster when there's fewer of them in a directory. Such structure spreads files thin.
- To not mess up *nix utilities like `rm`, which take a finite number of arguments and deleting large number of files at once tends to be hacky (having to pass it though `find` etc.)

What's the real reason? What is a "good" cache directory structure and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time I've done it, it has been to avoid slow linear searches in filesystems. Luckily, at least on Linux, this is becoming a thing of the past.

However, even today, with b-tree based directories, a very large directory will be hard to deal with, since it will take forever and a day just to get a listing of all the files, never mind finding the right file.

Comment: Ah, thought it had something to do with it. Would love to know which FS`s still use linear search. I'll wait for more answers before selecting one as accepted, thanks!

Comment: On Linux, ext2 and ext3 use linear search, unless the dir_index option is enabled for the filesystem (it's been the default for a while now). In general, old filesystems use linear, new ones use trees.

Answer (score 2):

Just use dates. Since you will remove by date. :)

Comment: My experience is that this can create performance problems, if you ever need to manually clear the cache - since all the files created immediately after (by prewarming the cache, or when the public hits some popular pages) will have near-identical timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `ls -l`, all the files need to be `stat()`ed to get details, which adds considerably to the listing time - this happens whether the FS uses hashed or linear structures.

So even if the FS has a capability of coping with incredibly large directory sizes, there are good reasons not to have large flat structures (They're also a pig to back up)

I've benchmarked GFS2 (clustered) with 32,000 files in a directory or arranged in a tree structure - recursive listings were around 300 times faster than getting a listing when they were all in a flat structure (could take up to 10 minutes to get a directory listing)

EXT4 showed similar ratios but as the end point was only a couple of seconds most people wouldn't notice.